# how to add object id to datagrid row in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I have a person class and empty datagrid in silverlight project.I want to add datarow in datagrid with c# code and hide person's id datarow.So User don't see id value.My aim is that I get id when I need to person's id.

**Person Class**

```
public class Personel
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string  isim { get; set; }
        public string soyisim { get; set; }
        public PersonType personType { get; set; }
        public string tckNo { get; set; }
        public PersonelAltSinif personbrans { get; set; }
        public string diplomano { get; set; }
        public string  sgkno { get; set; }
        public Vardiya vardiya { get; set; }
        public UzmanType uzmanType { get; set; }
        public  byte[]  img { get; set; }
    }
```

**Add Source code**

```
 List<Personel> plst = e.Result.ToList();
 dataPersonGrid.ItemsSource = plst;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the data grid columns instead of letting them be automatically generated, like so...

```
        <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dataPersonGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding isim}"></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding soyisim }"></sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
                <!-- etc -->
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        </sdk:DataGrid>
```

The `DataContext` of each row in your grid will now be a `Personel` object, but the user will not be able to see the `ID` field.

Comment: I wrote my code as your answer but datagrid is null.Will I add some code except source code( List<Personel> plst = e.Result.ToList();
 dataPersonGrid.ItemsSource = plst;) ?

Comment: Is the 'dataPersonGrid' null or is the 'plst' list empty? My code works with your original code example if 'plst' is not empty.

Comment: 'plst' list's count is 8. Do you add something in source code?

Comment: Now,it run perfectly.Thank you very much

Comment: I am glad I could help. On stack overflow, it is considered good practice to mark the response that helped you as "The Answer". Someone else might find it helpful to know which response was the one that helped.